# what would be a good approach to store a dictionary of dataframes in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, database, pandas, dataframe

Now I have a dictionary, where each key is corresponding to a 3-row dataframe(same kind), what would be a good way of storing this data in MySQL?

I am using python, pandas.

Thanks for any help!

Edit: 
Here is the format of each dataframe

```
  Col1 Col2
1 A  0.2
2 B  0.3
3 C  0.25
```

The purpose of the data is for searching. When we request by a key, I want to get all the information stored in its associated dataframe. Storing it in one table would be enough for future usage.

Comment: can you provide your data. how it looks

Comment: @ammy hi, I have added the format of each dataframe. The key of the dictionary is just a string, and it is associated with one such df.

Comment: That'd depend on what the data is supposed to be. Do you want to dump all your data to a single table, or something else? Add details.

Comment: hi @IljaEverilä , dumping all the data to one single table would be enough for my purpose.

Comment: I guess you could just [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the `values()` of your dictionary and write [`to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

Setup:

```
In [10]: df1
Out[10]:
  Col1  Col2
1    A  0.20
2    B  0.30
3    C  0.25

In [11]: df2
Out[11]:
  Col1   Col2
1    A  10.20
2    B  10.30
3    C  10.25

In [12]: df3
Out[12]:
  Col1   Col2
1    A  20.20
2    B  20.30
3    C  20.25

In [13]: dfs = {'df1':df1, 'df2':df2, 'df3':df3}
```

We can merge all of our DFs into one DF and add additional column containing the key:

```
In [15]: df = pd.concat([df.assign(idx=key) for key, df in dfs.items()], ignore_index=True)

In [16]: df
Out[16]:
  Col1   Col2  idx
0    A   0.20  df1
1    B   0.30  df1
2    C   0.25  df1
3    A  10.20  df2
4    B  10.30  df2
5    C  10.25  df2
6    A  20.20  df3
7    B  20.30  df3
8    C  20.25  df3
```

and save it to MySQL:

```
df.to_sql('table_name', engine, if_exists='...')
```

PS i would also consider adding an index based on the `'idx'` column in order to speed up access/searching in MySQL...